# Fold all regexp matches

Tags: regular-expressions, code-folding

I'm working on email templates using `web-mode`, which – alas – requires inline styling galore… many of my opening tags won't fit on a single line even on a 4K-Display due to the massive amount of Attributes.

In order to reduce the clutter when editing the content I would like to fold only the attributes of all HTML-tags. This could be achieved if there was a way to fold all strings matching the following regex: `"[[:alnum:]]+=[^>]+"` or the first group of this  one (probably safer): `"<[[:alnum:]]+ +\\([^>]+\\)>"`.

By folding I basically mean hiding the text, possibly having it replaced by a clickable placeholder revealing it when clicked. AucTex does it like that.The replacement part is not necessary htough. Basically all I need is to temporarily get the clutter out of sight, e.g.:

`<div class="someclass"> foo </div>` → `<div …> foo </div>`

I've tried `hs-mode`, but it seems to only operate on blocks, which won't work in my case since the Attributes are on the same line as the possible START and END regexes supposed to surround a block.

It should be possible to fold a regex, given the way e.g. AucTeX folds the content of certain macros etc. Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance

Oliver

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you mean by "folding a regexp" or folding all strings that match a given regexp. To me the question isn't too clear, but I'm guessing that a simple example would make it quite clear.

Comment: Sure, by folding I basically mean hiding the text, possibly having it replaced by a clickable placeholder revealing it when clicked. AucTex does it like that.The replacement part is not necessary htough. Basically all I need is to temporarily get the clutter out of sight, e.g.:
<div class="someclass"> foo </div>
→
<div …> foo </div>

Comment: Please put all such info in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following elisp code defines a new minor mode `web-hide-attr-mode`.
It is hooked to `web-mode`. So it is already active if you open a document in `web-mode`.

You can toggle it by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `web-hide-attr-mode`.

It works by adding an entry to `font-lock-keywords` that puts the `invisible` property `web-hide-attr` on the html attributes and by adding `web-hide-attr` to the `buffer-invisibility-spec`. It actually puts `(web-hide-attr . t)` there to generate the ellipses.

```el
(defconst web-hide-attr-font-lock-keywords
  '(("<[[:alnum:]]+ +\\([^>]+\\)>"
     1
     '(face default invisible web-hide-attr)
     'append t
     ))
  "Keywords for hiding attributes in `web-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode web-hide-attr-mode
  "Hide tag attributes in `web-mode'."
  :lighter " H"
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil web-hide-attr-font-lock-keywords)
  (if web-hide-attr-mode
      (add-to-invisibility-spec '(web-hide-attr . t))
    (remove-from-invisibility-spec '(web-hide-attr . t)))
  (font-lock-flush)
  (font-lock-ensure))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'web-hide-attr-mode)
```

Comment: Awesome… wouldn't have thought one had to go as far as to define a mode (have only done so twice in my Emacs life and without any font-stuff) Many thanks for the trouble! It works perfectly.